# Ethereum pending

Tags: blockchain

Sir, my ethereum is pending since 3 days before. I want to know when complet my transation. My hash
 0xbdcebd75a56d82f27528166923b818ce3f743f4093736900d56f65d17e3791e5. What can transaction lost permanently

Comment: Which network? No TX with this Hash on mainnet.

Comment: What i do. Where is my ethereum transation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a transaction should show up on Etherscan or any Ethereum explorer within minutes, and confirmation should be done within an hour (the confirmation time depends on the gas price you paid for). If the transaction isn't showing up after 3 days, it means your transaction didn't get broadcasted to the Ethereum network.

You should resend the transaction again. Since you mentioned you're using Bitbns wallet, your ether balance on Bitbns should remain unchanged as the transaction didn't go through, if this is not the case, you should ask Bitbns about this.

Answer (score 0):

This tx can't be found on Etherscan. You may have to rebroadcast the tx or create a new one as it likely didn't make it to the network.

Comment: Sir, please explain rebroadcast tx or creat a new one

Comment: How did you create that transaction? Just do that again

Comment: But i have no more ethareum in my wallet. I sent ethareum receiver wallet but not recieved. And search hash than show me (Sorry, we are unable to locate this Transaction Hash)

Comment: I did creat this transaction bitbns walllet (sender) to unocoin (reciever)

Comment: Ahhh, so you didn't send it from a wallet, you sent it from an *exchange*. You'll have to contact the support of that exchange to get further help.